# Copying Multiple Rows from One Sheet to A Target - Google Apps Script (...is not a function error)

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror

I am trying to write a script that will copy specific rows on a general source sheet and paste it to a target sheet. I know that there is a lot of examples of this online but there are some variations that do not work with my code, so it is difficult for me to apply (a novice).

Here is the code that I have written:

```
function singleSheetIOD() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2, 19, lr-3);
    ss.insertColumnAfter(18);
    ss.getRange(1,19,1,1).setValue('IOD');
    ss.getRange("S2").setFormula("=H2*R2");
    
ss.getRange("S2").copyTo(fillDownRange);

    const netSquare = ss.getRange('S2:S').getValues().flat().filter(v=>v!='');
    const sum = netSquare.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
    ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 20, 1, 1).setValue(sum);

    const value1 = ss.getRange(lr, 20).getValue();
    const value2 = ss.getRange(lr,9).getValue();
    const divisor = value1/value2;

    ss.getRange(lr,11,1,1).setValue(divisor);

%below this is the actual "copy and paste" attempt

  var lastTwoRows = ss.getRange(lr-1,1,2,11).getValues();
  var pastesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Summary');
    pastesheet.setValues(lastTwoRows);
}
```

I keep receiving this error: TypeError: pastesheet.setValues is not a function

It is important that I do not define the source Sheet by name (only the target sheet) because this is nested in a for loop that will loop across all other sheets in the spreadsheet.

Does anyone have an idea why I might be receiving this error?

Thank you so much.

AEB

Comment: Sheet doesn't have `setValues`. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation on **Class Sheet** to see available methods.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the `range` of the sheet you're looking to `setValues` on.

```
// Currently:
pastesheet.setValues(lastTwoRows);

// Needs to be:
pastesheet.getRange(...).setValues(lastTwoRows);
```

As of right now, you're trying to set the values on a sheet, but have not specified where to put them.

Note: The range **must** be equal to the size of the array you're setting.

**See:**

- [.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)